# How to clear ONLY the databound items from a ASP.NET DropDownList and NOT any items added in Source?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

The title pretty much asks the whole question - How can I clear ONLY the databound items from a ASP.NET DropDownList and NOT any items added in Source? If I have the following ddl:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" 
                  Width="300px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="(Please Select)" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

...and then call the following:

```
ddl1.Items.Clear()
```

The *all* the DDL ListItems go away and next time I rebind, the "(Please Select)" default option is gone.

Is there a more streamlined or elegant way to clear *only* the databound items but leave the "(Please Select)" default ListItem added in the source? I think I could call the Items.Clear() and pop that default item back in like `ddl1.Items.Add(New ListItem("(Please Select)", "0"))` as a new ListItem object, but I wondered if there was a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found no other *streamlined* or better way than clearing the list and then adding the default item back into the collection like shown below:

```
ddl1.Items.Clear()
ddl1.Items.Add(New ListItem("(Please Select)", "0"))
```

Comment: I failed to find a solution after several years. Your answer is simply the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

How about this easy trick. The best advantage of using this trick is that if you make a custom dropdown list as well, It will work. It has been tested and worked perfectly.

```
while (ddl1.Items.Count != 1)
    {
        ddl1.Items.RemoveAt(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if the prompt is always the first element, then it will be the 0th item in the items collection. so you could iterate through the items deleting from 1 to N.  there is a function to delete by index.

Comment: i wrote something like this:   

for (int i = 1; i < this.DropDownList1.Items.Count; i++)
{            
   this.DropDownList1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}

Comment: the other idea is to insert your prompt text in the databound event. 

e.g.

  protected void DropDownList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        this.DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "select");
  }

Comment: Yeah I *do* believe that would work, but I actually believe looping through all the items is less efficient than calling .Clear and then adding the default ListItem back in manually as I proposed. What I was really looking for was to see if I missed something like: ddl1.Items.ClearDataBound or something like that.

Comment: On another project I tried the looping technique you suggested, and your code snippet has to be modified as follows: `this.DropDownList1.Items.RemoveAt(1);` You can't remove at `i` because as items are being removed in the loop, and the value of `i` increases, you will get a **Index was out of range** exception once the value of `i` surpasses the number of elements remaining. Always remove at the '1' position until the count of items less 1 has been reached, and this too will preserve the 1st element in the list.